# Change info from day to day

Tags: ios

I'm fairly new to IOS developing and I'm developing an app where I display some information that I want to change automatically every day. The info is, for instance, opening hours that are different not only on the different days of the week but they are decided by season and weather.

I hope I don't get off topic here but what I would like to accomplish is simply for my `UITextView/UILable` to change accordingly to a calendar. I have done research on the subject but I have not found what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: You know what the current day is, and you presumably have information relevant for that day. All you have to do is match one to the other.

Comment: That was not very helpful but thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

You can see NSTimer class

```
(NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```